# rounding float field to 2 decimal places errors

Tags: sql

I have a field and am rounding up the values to 2 decimal places, after running me query 4.267 becomes 4.27 which is correct but 5.425 becomes 5.42 which is wrong help pls.

Comment: Which database are you using, and can you include your SQL code?

Comment: @tolixtall . . . Those are actually the rules for rounding values.  "5"s are rounded to the even number.

Comment: am using sql server 2008R2..here is my code...ROUND(q.GrossPremium*l.[Tbl 01],2)  as GrossPremium1 i also tried ROUND(CAST (q.GrossPremium as float)* CAST(l.[Tbl 01] as float),2) as GrossPremium1

Answer (score 0):

Use ROUND function, this function is avaliable on most databases.
You didn't mention your dtabase not show us your code, this is an example for MySql database:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/41862

```
select round( 5.425, 2 );

| round( 5.425, 2 ) |
|-------------------|
|              5.43 |
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2 here is my code...ROUND(q.GrossPremium*l.[Tbl 01],2)  as GrossPremium1 i also used  
ROUND(CAST (q.GrossPremium as float)* CAST(l.[Tbl 01] as float),2) as NewPrem